# Proxy does not return data

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have been working with the kafka-rest for a couple of weeks, but I am running into some issues that I cannot understand.  When I write data to the topic, I would expect that I would see that data semi-real time in the proxy.  What I am seeing is that the proxy will return data at random over many requests.  I have changed the min bytes and the fetch.ms but they do not seem to change the behavior.  Is there a setting that I am missing or is this just how the proxy works?  This is the URL that I am using for the get request:

```
http://{settings.ZookeeperClientPortAddress}:{settings.ZookeeperClientPort}/consumers/{settings.ConsumerGroupName}/instances/{settings.Name}/topics/{settings.TopicName}
```

It is pretty straightforward, but I must be missing something.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't mind the mis-labeled properties ({zookeeper})

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "What I am seeing is that the proxy will return data at random over many requests.". Furthermore, I am quite new to Kafka, but did you try to set `offsets.load.buffer.size` to zero?

Comment: I meant that I sent a message into the system on a single node, so there was no wait time for acknowledgement, and the REST request to get that data did not result in receiving that message.  As for that setting, I haven't tried that but that might make a difference.  I will have to check that out.